# Annoying MacWizz Ads

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, google-chrome

I have recently been having trouble with MacWizz ads on my Chrome browser. The ads started appearing this morning. Any ideas on how to remove them?

**An example image showing the ads**

[image: Examples of the ads]

**List of my Chrome Extensions**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a picture of what extensions you have installed. This is usually bloatware/malware that gets bundled with shady programs

Comment: @RushilSrivastava updated my post

Comment: https://malwaretips.com/blogs/ads-by-macwizz-removal/

Comment: I wonder if we could reformat your question?  the picture of the extensions list is a little tricky to work with.

Answer (score 1):

With AdblockPlus, you can **right-click** on an ad and click **Block Element** to block that ad specifically, and from there it *normally* blocks those ads in the future. Or, you can follow the steps as shown in this link: https://malwaretips.com/blogs/ads-by-macwizz-removal/

Answer (score 0):

One of your best options would be to install [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com) and initiate a scan of your computer. It should remove the malware automatically.